# setting both pandas.read_table field & record separators

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a file which uses two colons in a row *(::)* to separate fields, and a pipe to separate records.  So, the datafile test.txt might look like this:

```
testcol1::testcol2|testdata1::testdata2
```

And my code is as follows:

```
pd.read_table('test.txt', sep='::', lineterminator='|')
```

This produces the following **warning:**

```
C:\Users\jordan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:4: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
```

And the following "parsed" data:

```
testcol1   testcol2|testdata1   testdata2
```

...with three columns, one header row, and zero data rows.  If I add the **engine=c** kwarg, I get the following **error:**

```
ValueError: the 'c' engine does not support regex separators
```

It appears as though Python thinks my **::** field separator is a regex pattern, and thus forces me to use the Python parser, which does not support the **lineterminator** kwarg.  How do I tell pandas to use the c parser, and to do a simple string match rather than a regex match for my field separator?

Comment: One possibility is to read the file using the c engine which will be quicker and then split the columns and data as a post processing step: `df = pd.read_csv('test.txt',  lineterminator=r'|')` and then`df1 = df['testcol1::testcol2'].str.split('::', expand=True)
df1.columns = list(df.columns.str.split('::', expand=True)[0])`

Comment: Even though I'm looking for a way to get Pandas to work (it seems broken here), I'm marking the one answer as correct, since it's a valid workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the file using the c engine which will be faster so you can use the `lineterminator` param and then split the columns and data as a post-processing step using vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [20]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""testcol1::testcol2|testdata1::testdata2"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),  lineterminator=r'|')
df

Out[20]:
     testcol1::testcol2
0  testdata1::testdata2

In [37]:
df1 = df['testcol1::testcol2'].str.split('::', expand=True)
df1.columns = list(df.columns.str.split('::', expand=True)[0])
df1

Out[37]:
    testcol1   testcol2
0  testdata1  testdata2
```